# How to get variable from JSON in android studio

Tags: android, json

I am trying to get a single string from a JSON response.("oppdatert")

The following line is returned when i run my function:

> {"isError":false,"errorMsg":null,"response":{"oppdatert":"ja"}}

This is an async-task, and under **onTaskComplete** i have the following code:

```
String approved = null;
JSONArray myJsonArray = JSONreturn.getJSONArray("response");

myList.clear();

for(int i = 0; i < myJsonArray.length(); i++) {

     JSONObject brukerOppdatert = myJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     approved = brukerOppdatert.getString("oppdatert");
```

The application crashes after "JSONArray = myJsonArray = ..."

This method have worked on other json-array, but the difference is that in the past there have been more then one object.

any ideas?

Comment: your response is  `JSONObject` not `JSONArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your response is JSONObject not JSONArray. so

```
JSONObject myJsonobject = JSONreturn.getJSONObject("response");

myList.clear();

myJsonobject.getString("oppdatert");
```

So

> myJsonobject.getString("oppdatert")

this will get you, your required string.

Comment: I have tried this, and im getting "No value for response"

Comment: I solved it! i just had to do: JSONObject myJsonObject = JSONreturn;
Thx for your answer!

Comment: @Toby I'm gald you solved your problem